# Matching a record with multiple records in SQL Server (multiple relationships)

Tags: sql-server

I need to match the date of a user's action with their subscription number at the time. One record in the `Subscription` table relates to multiple rows in `Action` table and the link between the two isn't the month (!) or month + year as the subscription lasts throughout many months when the user takes action up until the new subscription date comes into effect.

E.g. all dates of User's action taken between Jun 2011-Mar 2012 should relate to `Subscription` date of May 2011 because this subscription date was in effect until the next subscription was singed in May 2012 and this one lasted up unit another one was singed in Aug 2015.

I have users with different number of subscription so the code needs to be general enough to embrace multiple or a very few subscriptions vs. action dates.

For example, in tb1 with the logs of User's actions I have multiple records

```
Jun, 2011    (should link to Subnumber1 active between May 2011- Apr 2012)
Aug, 2011    (should link to Subnumber1 active between May 2011- Apr 2012)
Dec, 2011    (should link to Subnumber1 active between May 2011- Apr 2012)
Mar, 2012    (should link to Subnumber1 active between May 2011- Apr 2012)
May, 2012    (should link to Subnumber2 active between May 2012- Jul 2015)
Jun, 2015    (should link to Subnumber2 active between May 2012- Jul 2015)
```

Then in the other table I have user's subscription numbers

```
May, 2011  Subnumber1
May, 2012  Subnumber2
Aug, 2015  Subnumber3
```

So basically, for the action that took place in May 2012 the query should return Subnumber2

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you post better sample data?  Are you using real dates or just the month, year?

Comment: You need to post your table definitions. In the absence of that this would appear to be the simple query `SELECT * FROM Subscriptions INNER JOIN  Actions ON Actions.ActionDate BETWEEN Subscriptions.StartDate AND Subscriptions.EndDate`

Comment: The only problem is that there are multiple subscription numbers between the start date and end date. Each time they renew a subscription, it becomes yet another start date.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output you want:

```
declare @subscription table(start_date datetime, sub varchar(10))
insert into @subscription(start_date, sub) values
('May, 2011', 'Subnumber1')
, ('May, 2012', 'Subnumber2')
, ('Aug, 2015', 'Subnumber3')

declare @action table(record datetime)
insert into @action values
('Jun, 2011'), ('Aug, 2011'), ('Dec, 2011'), ('Mar, 2012'), ('May, 2012'), ('Jun, 2015')

Select a.record, s.sub, s.start_date, s.end_date From @action as a 
Inner Join (
    Select s1.start_date, e.end_date, s1.sub from @subscription as s1
    outer apply (
        Select end_date = min(s2.start_date) from @subscription as s2
            Where s1.start_date < s2.start_date
    ) as e
) as s on a.record >= s.start_date and (a.record < s.end_date or s.end_date is null)
```

> record                 sub      start_date end_date
>
> 2011-06-01 00:00:00.000   Subnumber1  2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 2012-05-01 00:00:00.000
>   2011-08-01 00:00:00.000 Subnumber1  2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 2012-05-01 00:00:00.000
>   2011-12-01 00:00:00.000 Subnumber1  2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 2012-05-01 00:00:00.000
>   2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 Subnumber1  2011-05-01 00:00:00.000 2012-05-01 00:00:00.000
>   2012-05-01 00:00:00.000 Subnumber2  2012-05-01 00:00:00.000 2015-08-01 00:00:00.000
>   2015-06-01 00:00:00.000 Subnumber2  2012-05-01 00:00:00.000 2015-08-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: Thank you for your response. This would work great if there was a fixed number of subscriptions per user. Unfortunately, a user can have 8, 10, 20 subscription numbers, each with their own start/end date so I can't hard code this to account for differences between thousands of customers.

Comment: nothing is hardcoded. I just created a couple table variables with sample data. Provide your data model and sample data and I will update my answer. you can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to build a simplified data model with sample data.